# How to move multiple layers to another tab in Photoshop

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, layers

I usually don't work with photography, so I apologize if my question sounds stupid, but I am doing a small project, and I need help with Photoshop and layers.

I have one image with multiple different layers and groups. I would like to save everything as one and move it to a new tab in the same Photoshop window. Is it possible to use the project with layers in the second tab as a whole, but if I modify something on the original tab, that the copied "image" on the second tab is automatically updated, so I don't need to save the first image every time and manually import it to the second one? Or is there any other solution for this?

Comment: This is not related to photography. It is not. It's related to using Photoshop for photography in partic... Oh hi Marc!

Comment: And welcome to Photo.SE! I think the question is about using Photoshop in general, while this site focusses on photography. Are you doing this in a photography context? If so, perhaps you can add that to your question? Regardless, I think you're looking for [linked smart objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html#create-linked-smart-objects)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not related to photography, but to the use of Photoshop.

Comment: Maybe this will explain how to do it, https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/copy-and-paste-layers-from-one-psd-file-to-another/m-p/3222210

Comment: Off topic but just to help you out.. if you drag the tabs down they will window, then once you can see parts of two images you can then drag layers from one to the other. Investigate smart objects to have the parts ‘follow’ you

Comment: Use of Photoshop to work with photographs *is* on topic here. Only if the use of Photoshop was with non photographic source material(s) would it be off topic. Even if the specific use case here is with source material that is not a photograph, [if it can also be applied to working with photographs](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28/15871) in PS it would still be on topic. Just as questions concerned with application to producing video can be on topic if the same problem can be encountered shooting still photographs. Lighting, composition, lenses, processing apps, etc. are on topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can place the first image (or a version if it with the layers you want) into the second image as a smart object. Then by editing that smart object you can open a new window with the embedded version and edit the two files in the way you describe.

Note you will have to save the embedded smart object to update the parent document.